# Software/tool to test/check web-application in multiple browsers?

Tags: cross-browser

I am working in creating a website and I want to check in multiple browsers for Browser Compatibility test automatically by using Automated Test Tool. Do you guys know if there is any software/tool where I can just give a link and it loads the page in multiple browsers?

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/) before and it's ok if you don't mind waiting for an hour or two.

I'd also recommend checking out some of the links on [Delicious](http://delicious.com/search?p=browser).

Comment: Browser Shots appears to be down at present ("No active screenshot factories.")

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [litmus](http://litmusapp.com/), from the people who brought you [doctype](http://www.doctype.com), part of the [League of Justice](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/why-cant-you-have-just-one-site/). 14-day passes to test your layouts in 24 browsers [currently cost](http://litmusapp.com/pricing) $39.

Comment: Yup.  litmus is decent especially for testing email marketing.  Remember, you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of XenoCode's ["Spoon Browser Sandbox"](http://spoon.net/browsers/) myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium RC (Selenium 1) or Selenium 2 (WebDriver) for automated test. But You have to record the test using Selenium IDE on Firefox browser and writing some tests on it. Selenium supports FF, Chrome, IE, Safari and Opera.

Comment: You can visit the following URL for learning Selenium:  http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 0):

If the website is publicly visible then there are web based services that you can use such as http://crossbrowsertesting.com/.

If your website is internal only, then you're going to struggle to find support I think. We tried to find one but all we found were services that require a publicly visible website - no good for testing pre-go-live.

Comment: Litmus works with websites that are password-protected, so as long as you can publish your site to somewhere on the internet, it'll work for you.

Comment: @Dominic Yes, that's why I up-voted your answer, it's a good option as well. Unfortunately our production department require a lot of notice and even more forms filled out before any of our code goes near a public facing server because they do a lot for us in terms of security and firewalls.

Comment: I imagine someone could make a decent business out of making an "inhouseable" solution to this (i.e. running on a server within your company's firewalls).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a compatible design or compatible JS? Because AJAX functionality is difficult to test with the usual cross-browser tools.

For the latter, look at [httpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/), though I'm not sure it can simulate multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Microsoft Expression Web SuperPreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx), but I haven't tried it so can't comment on if it's good or not.

Their opening quote makes me laugh though, mainly because of how sucky IE6 is:

> About 7 years ago, the browser wars
>   were over. Internet Explorer had
>   become the de facto standard, and for
>   a while, there were very few
>   compatibility issues in web page
>   design.

Check it out though, might be worthwhile. Especially if you are a .NET developer, however it might be useful to web developers in general.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has [BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/index.html). It requires an Adobe account (free) and gives you Firefox 2.0 - 3.5 (WinXP, OSX), IE 6-8 (WinXP), Safari 3-4 (OSX) and Chrome 3.0 (WinXP).